# Verifying CNOT on different qubits of a 3 - qubit system yields this measurement state

Tags: quantum-circuit, logical-gates

Below is a circuit involving two CNOT unitary gates that yields a post - measurement state $|a, b, a \oplus b \rangle$.

I am struggling to convince myself this is true.

[image]

Let $|a\rangle, |b\rangle$ be two input qubit for a CNOT gate. Then, the action of a CNOT on $|a\rangle, |b\rangle$ is as follows: $CNOT(|a\rangle, |b\rangle) = |a\rangle |b \oplus a\rangle$

1. Just after the first CNOT

   $CNOT(|a\rangle, |0\rangle) = |a\rangle | 0 \oplus a \rangle$. In otherwords, $|a\rangle$ is unchanged but $|c\rangle$ which was $|0\rangle$ is now $|0 \oplus a\rangle$.
2. Just after the second CNOT

   $CNOT(|b\rangle |c\rangle) = |b\rangle |(0 \oplus a) \oplus b\rangle$

How can I get unstuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Remember,

$\begin{align}
0 \oplus 0 &= 0\,.\\
0 \oplus 1 &= 1\,.\\
\therefore 0 \oplus a &= a\,.
\end{align}$

---

- Let your initial state be $|\psi_0\rangle$.
  $$ \therefore |\psi_0\rangle = |a \rangle_1 |b\rangle_2 |0\rangle_3 \,,$$
  where the subscript denotes which qubit it is.
- Let state after the first $CNOT$ be $|\psi_1\rangle$.

$$ \begin{align}\therefore |\psi_1\rangle &= CNOT_{1\to3}|\psi_0\rangle\,,\\ &= |a \rangle_1 |b\rangle_2 |0 \oplus a\rangle_3\,,\\ &= |a \rangle_1 |b\rangle_2 |a\rangle_3\,.\end{align}$$

- Let the state after the second $CNOT$ be $|\psi_2\rangle$.
  $$ \begin{align}\therefore|\psi_2\rangle &=  CNOT_{2\to3}|\psi_1\rangle\,,\\ &= |a \rangle_1 |b\rangle_2 | a \oplus b\rangle_3\,,\\ &= |a,b,a \oplus b\rangle_{123} \,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help.